# Trying to create a home page with a login form, but getting 'NameError: name 'url' is not defined'

Tags: python, django, forms, url, authentication

I'm relatively new to django and trying to create a home page that has a login form on it, consisting of username and pw bars. I was trying to recreate what I saw here in my own project:

[homepage login form Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208562/homepage-login-form-django)

but I keep getting back
NameError: name 'url' is not defined. I am pretty lost on what is causing this. I was initially writing into the project level urls.py but then moved to the app level (accounts) urls.py because that makes sense to me...but I'm not confident about this.

Here are my files:

```
project
    ├── manage.py
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── templates
    ├── accounts
    |     ├──migrations
    |     ├──_pycache_
    |     ├──admin.py
    |     ├──apps.py
    |     ├──models.py
    |     ├──_init__.py
    |     ├──urls.py
    |     ├──tests.py
    |     └──views.py
    └── project
          ├── settings.py
          ├── urls.py
          └── wsgi.py
```

project/settings.py

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
import os
...
SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login')
LOGIN_REDIRECT__URL = reverse_lazy('home')
LOGOUT_REDIRECT__URL = '/'
    enter code here
```

project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', include('posts.urls')),
]
```

accounts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    url(r'^accounts/', HomeView.as_view(template_name='../templates/home.html', name='home')),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout'),
]
```

accounts/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(HomeView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

templates/home.html

```
    <!--user checks-->
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class = "greeting">
        Hi {{ user.username }}!
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class = "register">
        <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">sign up!</a>
    </div>
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
    <form method = "post" action = "{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <!--username bar-->
    <div class="container-2">
        {{ form.username.label_tag }}
        {{ form.username }}
    </div>

    <!--pw bar-->
    <div class="container-3">
        {{ form.password.label_tag }}
        {{ form.password }}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </form>


    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: Maybe you want to add in accounts/urls.py: from django.conf.urls import url

Answer (score 0):

You need to import url in accounts/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```